# How to parse a file with several delimiters

Tags: java

i need to parse a file of this format,such that i can get/fetch the values present in place of those tags by avoiding linefeeds or "/n",carriage return 0r "/r",^^(spaces). just give me an idea with sample code such that it helps me in proceeding.....

^^^
M^^^COMPLD
(^^^"[,]:,,, [],
[], [], [] [, ]
[:[], [] [,
[,]]
[:[][,]]]")* ;

ASSUME THAT RESPONSE IS OF THIS TYPE:i need to fetch each and every field value,

RTRV-HDR:::RH01;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:03
M  RH01 COMPLD
;
agent>RTRV-EQPT::ALL:RE01;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:04
M  RE01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-9,IOC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-10,IOC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-1,NMC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-2,NMC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:IS-NR"
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA01;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:05
M  RA01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:CR,PROC_FAIL,SA,09-11-18,13-48-54,,:\"Processor Failure\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA02::MJ,;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:06
M  RA02 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA03::MN,;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:06
M  RA03 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA04::MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:10
M  RA04 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-PM-EQPT::ALL:RP01;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:11
M  RP01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-1,180.080,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-2,204.660,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-3,230.500,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-4,187.580,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:BATTERYPWR-1,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:BATTERYPWR-2,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-1,180.080,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-2,204.660,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-3,230.500,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-4,187.580,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:BATTERYPWR-1,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:BATTERYPWR-2,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
;
agent>INIT-SYS::SLOT-1-1-2:IS01::1;
[2K

SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:11
M  IS01 COMPLD
;
agent>

thanks for all valuable replies

Comment: which delimiter you are using, or atleast mention the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite short, so it's difficult to guess what you mean, but maybe using a [StreamTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) might help.

Comment: ya i am doing using stream tokenizer but its not a good solution because i dont know how values for many fields i wil get at each time as output

Comment: You can still use the StreamTokenizer here, you just have to decide for yourself by parsing the data where your new record starts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have an on-the-fly aggregator which takes that input and glues coherent lines together, making your expressions easier to do on those lines instead. F.ex. you could have an Iterator which wraps another iterator with those lines you wrote, looks for coherent lines and storing those in a StringBuffer. When you've found all coherent lines to form one line you return it in the next() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use StringTokenizer

```java
String s = "";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("yourString" , "-,\n"); //You can add delimiters
while(!(st.hasMoreTokens())){
s += st.nextToken() + "\n";
}
```