# how fetch each field as a value frm file

Tags: java, parsing

how to parse this kind of response such that i can fetch each and every field as seperate value by avoiding all the delimiters as `::,-,;,\n,\r` etc........pls give me an idea of doing such that i can proceed

```
RTRV-HDR:::RH01;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:03
M  RH01 COMPLD
;
agent>RTRV-EQPT::ALL:RE01;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:04
M  RE01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-9,IOC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-1-10,IOC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-1,NMC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-2,NMC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:IS-NR"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:IS-NR"
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA01;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:05
M  RA01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:CR,PROC_FAIL,SA,09-11-18,13-48-54,,:\"Processor Failure\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA02::MJ,;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:06
M  RA02 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA03::MN,;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:06
M  RA03 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA04::MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:10
M  RA04 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
agent>RTRV-PM-EQPT::ALL:RP01;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:11
M  RP01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-1,180.080,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-2,204.660,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-3,230.500,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:FANCURRENT-4,187.580,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:BATTERYPWR-1,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:BATTERYPWR-2,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-1,180.080,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-2,204.660,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-3,230.500,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:FANCURRENT-4,187.580,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:BATTERYPWR-1,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:BATTERYPWR-2,53.650,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-5,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-6,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-7,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-1-8,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-3,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-4,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-5,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-6,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-7,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:LASERPWR-1,200.00,,,,,"
   "SLOT-1-2-8,OLC:LASERPWR-2,200.00,,,,,"
;
agent>INIT-SYS::SLOT-1-1-2:IS01::1;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-18 13:49:11
M  IS01 COMPLD
;
agent>
```

Comment: What is a 'field' in your input?

Comment: in my point  of view field is nothing but each and every word seperated by sum delimiter .....

Comment: consider one from above pasted thing that is:
 "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\"," 


from this i want to seperate SLOT,1,1,1
CMP:MN
T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH
NSA
01-10-09
00-00-00
\"Fan-T\"," 
and null if null is present between any two delimiters as ex: hari,,
then 1st value =hari 
2nd value=null as nothing is present between cammas(,)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754113/how-to-parse-a-file-with-several-delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Look at [java.util Scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) or [java.util.scanner.next(Pattern)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)