# parsing problem

Tags: java, parsing

hi every one i need to parse the following one such that it wil store each line in an array
avoiding emptyline asthere r two new lines after `[2K`

```
RTRV-ALM-EQPT::ALL:RA01;
[2K


   SIMULATOR 09-11-20 13:52:15
M  RA01 COMPLD
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:CR,PROC_FAIL,SA,09-11-20,13-51-55,,:\"Processor Failure\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\","
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
;
```

Comment: What have you tried (StreamTokenizer, StringUtils...) and what did not work?

Comment: Is this different from yesterday's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754113/how-to-parse-a-file-with-several-delimiters ?

Answer (score 3):

A rough outline:

1. Read a line
2. call line.trim() to remove whitechars
3. If line is not empty after trim: add line to Collection
4. After all lines have been processed, convert Collection to String[]

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
public static String[] lines = {
"SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MN,T-FANCURRENT-1-HIGH,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Fan-T\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-1,CMP:MJ,T-BATTERYPWR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-09,00-00-00,,:\"Battery-T\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-2,CMP:CR,PROC_FAIL,SA,09-11-20,13-51-55,,:\"Processor Failure\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA, 01-10-07,13-21-03,,:\"Laser-T\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-3,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA, 01-10-02,21-32-11,,:\" Laser-T\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MN,T-LASERCURR-1-HIGH,SA,01-10-05,02-14-03,,:\"Laser-T\",",
   "SLOT-1-1-4,OLC:MJ,T-LASERCURR-2-LOW,NSA,01-10-04,01-03-02,,:\"Laser-T\","
};
```

Comment: Perfect answer for unknown's question, as he wanted a solution for the give document (only) :-)